# How to run a command line in different folders - loop

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, code

I am facing a problem trying to run the following command line :

```
laszip *.laz
```

That command is supposed to uncompress all the files which are in the folder I am in, from the cmd.

I am supposed to run that command line to tens of folders containing files I need to uncompress. All the folders have the same patterns of names and look like : `LIDARHD_1-0_LAZ_PL-0912_6533-2021` or `LIDARHD_1-0_LAZ_PL-0912_6533-2021`

To save some time, I am trying to generate a code running the command line `laszip .*laz` to all the folders containing the `.laz` files I need to uncompressed.

I would be delighted if one of you could help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following command directly in your CMD :

```
cd your_root_path
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /a:d') do (
cd %a
laszip *.laz
)
```

`your_root_path` is the path from which you want to start the recursive search for `.laz` files

Don't forget to use double `%` instead of a single if you want to use this as a script

Comment: It worked !!! thank you